# responsive table with multiple columns in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to find an answer as for "nth" amount of columns in a table of bootstrap. Some guys asked it before but still there has been no solution. So, my question is how to manage with the responsiveness of columns. Let's say I have 5 colunms with its own names. 
| the streets' names | Victoria | Lombard | Champs-Elysées | Chervonoarmeyskaya | 
(without abbreviation, as a reader has to understand)

My solution were:

a) Playing with font-size, making it smaller to adapt it to 320px size. but succeed with 480px (at least for readable size).

b) Removing all padding at ".table thead > tr > th, .table tbody > tr > th," with @media (max-width: 480px) to get more space.

c) and the last one is to add condition like (switching automatically the screen size if "320px, 360px" onto "480px, 640px").

I don't know if it's good idea?

will it work correctly on all small devices like iphone, ipod, samsung ..., nokia ..., sony etc... with cross-browser compatibility? if so how to realize it?

here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="alert alert-info">
                <th>the streets' names</th>
                <th>Victoria</th>
                <th>Lombard</th>
                <th>Champs-Elysées</th>
                <th>Chervonoarmeyskaya</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td>Australia</td>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>France</td>
                <td>Ukraine</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</table>
```

P.S. If someone will find solution, consider about 7-10 columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about working with standard tables in bootstrap but have come across a couple of plugins that work really well with making tables responsive.

[**FooTable**](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable)

I haven't actually used FooTables but it looks awesome. It collapses specified columns into expandable section.

[**Datatables**](https://github.com/Comanche/datatables-responsive) (responsive version)

This i have used and uses the same functionality of **FooTables** but with the **Datatables** look and api. The link shows specifically how to integrate with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best solution in this case for small devices is to just hide some less important columns. Offer an option to see more columns, but let the users realize they will get a scrollbar.

It's simply not nicely possible to put that many columns on such a small screen. It is also pretty accepted that mobile versions show less or show it in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has less to do with Bootstrap and more to do with selecting an approach to use for responsive tables in general. Here are some methods that I've tried before to deal with tables at small resolutions:

- Using Bootstrap's `table-responsive` class and just having a horizontal scrollbar.
- Hiding less important columns as per [this technique](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/responsive_design_approach_for_complex_multicolumn_data_tables/) documented by Filament Group.
- Reformatting the table using CSS so that it no longer resembles a table at all as per [this method](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) by Chris Coyier.

There are also some other [responsive table](http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns) options. The one you select will likely depend upon the context of your site and personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with a horizontal jQuery accordian. [Here's an example using pictures](http://www.armagost.com/zaccordion/a-barebones-example/) and you could use it to display one column of your table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the responsive option to deal with many columns.
https://github.com/DataTables/Responsive
Include dataTables with the right bootstrap version and then:

```
$('#table').DataTable(
    {
     responsive: true 

    }
);
```